# ASP.NET Identity OWIN / Saved claims cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, claims-based-identity

I receive token from Facebook API and then add it as claim for user's identity:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = apiId,
    AppSecret = appSecret,
    Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ExternalAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

But when try to get this token, it turns out, there is no such claim.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var claimIdenties = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var token = claimIdenties?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Type == "ExternalAccessToken");

    return View();
}
```

It means that **token** variable will be null. Any suggestion what it can be?
Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294698/store-and-retrieve-facebook-access-token-in-asp-net-mvc-5-app-using-owin)

Comment: Does `claimIdentities` have anything in it? Does the action or controller have the `Authorize` attribute applied?

Comment: I had a similar problem once and I think the thing is on the creation of the claim, i.e., `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String)`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, `claimIdentities` have 4 claims and controller have `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: @dcg It did not help. But thank you for suggestion!

Comment: Adding claim to an identity does not do anything. Identity data is taken from the cookie. If you would like to preserve claim for further requests, you need to reset the cookie via `SignOut` and `SignIn` with updated claims. And even with that there is a risk of loosing that claim when `SecurityStampValidator` is used - it does not preserve the custom claims.

Comment: @tralmax Thanks! I will try!